# Why does my image texture only work on simple geometry?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv

I have a Principled BSDF material with an image texture. I want to replace the material I have used before with that material. When I assign this material to a simple mesh (for example a cube as shown in the picture below) everything works fine.

[image: pic1]

But it does not work with more complex geometry. Only the viewport color is shown and not the material.

Below is my (very simple) material configuration:
[image: pic2]

This is the configuration of the old material (only for completeness):
[image: pic3]

I have imported the complex geometry as .stl files.

Comment: May i ask if the more complicated object is UV unwrapped? It looks like the case of all UVs being stuck in a corner of the texture, essentially showing only one color of that pixel there.

Comment: I will try to check that, thanks. But why does it work with the previous material?

Comment: My guess is UV mapping. UV mapping instructs Blender how a flat 2D textures should be mapped to the surface of the 3D object. The default cube has been, already UV unwrapped. I'm guessing your new more complex map has not been UV unwrapped. Not being UV unwrapped often means that all the vertices are mapped to a single point in the UV Editor. Single point, will be a single pixel color appearing on the mesh.

Comment: You were right UV unwrapping was the problem. Now I will only have to figure out how to unwrap my geometry... Is there a way to construct my material in a way, so that no unwrapping is necessary?

Comment: You used box mapping on the texture of the old shader.

Comment: As you are using an image texture,  the mesh will need to be unwrapped. You could simply try the different UV options in the UV mapping menu, (perhaps the Cube Projection option would look ok) but in the long term you will just have to knuckle down and learn how/where to add Seams by hand, UV unwrap and edit the resulting unwrap. For this model just adding seams on all the 90° edges would do it but you would still need to go into the UV Editor and edit (move, rotate and scale) the UV islands so that wood textures looks ok.

Comment: You can't use an image texture and expect it to magically wrap itself around the object correctly. To understand texture coordinates watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)